# > Cannot isolate parameters com.android.build.gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[Excuse me.. i want to ask about the problem about android studio that can not do build. I've tried several times to figure out how to solve this in other media such as google and youtube to get the core problem is permission on pc. after I tried some things that way, but I still experienced the exact same error when doing the build on android studio. Then how do I resolve the error? Thank.

> Cannot isolate parameters com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AarResourcesCompilerTransform$Parameters_Decorated@67b2faec of artifact transform AarResourcesCompilerTransform
> > Could not isolate value com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AarResourcesCompilerTransform$Parameters_Decorated@67b2faec of type AarResourcesCompilerTransform.Parameters
> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
> > Failed to transform aapt2-4.1.2-6503028-windows.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.1.2-6503028) to match attributes {artifactType=_internal-android-aapt2-binary, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for Aapt2Extractor: C:\Users\BUDIYANTO.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.tools.build\aapt2\4.1.2-6503028\6d9042942daa27a40e3ff66254cb2a82a7f0b69f\aapt2-4.1.2-6503028-windows.jar.
> > Failed to create directory 'C:\Users\BUDIYANTO.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0acdb043263d98cb86ad08d6f4b1bd1a\aapt2-4.1.2-6503028-windows'][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLCOc.png)

Answer (score 12):

Cannot isolate the issue but you can try these things if the caches got scrambled or something

1. try clean build or invalidate caches/restart
2. If the above didn't work delete the build/caches folder and rerun.
   From what I can see you can go here `C:\Users\BUDIYANTO.gradle\caches` and delete the caches folder, this will most certainly resolve your issue.
3. If that also didn't work the ultimate resort would be nuking the caches

   - Close Android Studio
   - open terminal and go to project location (cd project location)
   - ./gradlew clean
   - ./gradlew --stop
   - rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches
   - ./gradlew assembleDebug
   - Open Android Studio and gradle sync

Comment: Simply Invalidate Cache & Restart worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

first clean project from build tool and then sync