# While running create a react native app. It throws an error as 'Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources''. How to solve it?

Tags: android, react-native

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Could not isolate parameters com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AarResourcesCompilerTransform$Parameters_Decorated@7782372 of artifact transform AarResourcesCompilerTransform
> Could not isolate value com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AarResourcesCompilerTransform$Parameters_Decorated@7782372 of type AarResourcesCompilerTransform.Parameters
> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:detachedConfiguration2'.
> > Failed to transform aapt2-7.4.2-8841542-windows.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:7.4.2-8841542) to match attributes {artifactType=_internal-android-aapt2-binary, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for Aapt2Extractor: C:\Users\Manuj98.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.tools.build\aapt2\7.4.2-8841542\676fb7c1e3125403a1908b9a77071e7897085ca3\aapt2-7.4.2-8841542-windows.jar.
> > Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66166324/cannot-isolate-parameters-com-android-build-gradle